# Does German have an ancient (obsolete) verb for the action of opening a book?

Tags: etymology

Does German have an ancient (obsolete) verb for the action of opening a book?

For example, in Russian we say otkrit' (open the book), but in the Old Slavonic the verb razognuti (to unbend the book) was used.

Answer (score 3):

An antiquated verb for to open is

> **aufthun** ([deprecated in 1902](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aufthun)), since then **auftun**

and therefore you can find

> Ein Buch aufthun.
>
> Ein Buch auftun.

Old examples can be found in Grimm's Wörterbuch [here (Buch, Abs. 2)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GB12398#XGB12398) and [here (aufthun, Abs. 7)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA07210#XGA07210). Another example: [Bible - Revelation 5:2 + 5:3](http://www.transcripture.com/deutsch-englisch-offenbarung-5.html)

> Und ich sah einen starken Engel, der rief aus mit großer Stimme: Wer ist würdig, das Buch aufzutun und seine Siegel zu brechen? Und niemand im Himmel noch auf Erden noch unter der Erde konnte das Buch auftun und hineinsehen.

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auftun) describes it as elevated outdated.

---

But watch out. Nowadays it sounds rather childish ("Tu mal das Buch auf") than outdated or it can be understood as a (unusual) way to say you "discovered/located" something.

Comment: Wie sagt man denn "aufthun", um es von "auftun" abzugrenzen? Oder meinst Du Schreiben?

Comment: @userunknown Jein. Spitzfindig ausgedrückt sind sowohl sagen als auch schreiben in dem Satz missverständlich und nicht zu 100% korrekt. Schließlich kann man aufthun zwar auch heute so schreiben, aber dann ists halt nach heutigem Stand ein Schreibfehler ^^. Ich werde es entsprechend anpassen.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to this question, but too long for a comment.

Obviously, [there](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500551/do-the-english-have-an-ancient-obsolete-verb-for-the-action-of-the-book-openin) is the same question for English language on SE.

In one of its comments by @HotLicks, the English verb *to crack* is suggested. In English, the usage of *to crack* for opening a book seems obsolete. Beware, that the German word *aufschlagen* means both, *crack (an egg)* and *open (a book)*.

However, the word *aufschlagen* in the sense of *to open a book* is **not** obsolete, but the very contrary is the case: It is the most common way to say to open a book.

Comment: very interesting, but a) *flip a book open* is also comon, and *umschlagen* (of the weather, or any other situation) has little to do with *crack*, and *flipped weather* would be figurative at best. Yet compare *break of dawn*, *der Morgen bricht an*.

Comment: @vectory Did you misread the word? It is not _umschlagen_, but _aufschlagen_.

Comment: I'm naturally referring the idea to *eine Buchseite umschlagen*. Sorry if that was not apparent. *umblättern* is of course the more frequent alternative.

Comment: also compare *Klappe* ~ *Umschlag* - *cover*, *envelope*.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to open a book in German is

> ein Buch aufschlagen

Literally this means *to knock a book open*. You never ever *öffnen* a book. This also applies to notebooks, journals, newspapers, paper files, etc.

This is certainly an ancient use of the verb *aufschlagen*, nevertheless it's not obsolete at all.

Comment: Natürlich kann man Bücher öffnen.

Comment: Ich wüsste niemanden, der so etwas sagt.

Comment: I would be so strict to say that nobody uses "ein Buch öffnen", but "aufschlagen ist definitely more common. "Buch öffnen" is not a common word combination, as least it is not mentioned here https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Buch

Answer (score -1):

There's also ***aufklappen***.I do not know how old this is, because I have how to check that.

The front and back cover of a book is the *Klappe*, like the lid of a case. We say idiomatically *es klappt nicht* when something *does not work*, and I suppose thus originally meant that: something won't fit, hold or close; I'd prefer to compare this to *kleben* "glue, stick", but I'm not sure of the roots; Cp. *see if it sticks*. Which is what I will do: Write down my thoughts, see if it sticks.

Surely *clip* is related. I'd further compare *club* "stick, batton; "closed society, association, conglomeration" (also compare *Offiziers-Stab*, *staff*), though *clobber* also belongs there. Going a bit further, compare *key*, PIE *(s)kleh2u "peg, nail", *Schlüssel* "key", *schließen* "to close", *aufschließen* "to unkey, open with a key", Ger. *klaffend* "gaping open", *clover* "segmented thing, of cleaves"; Then compare *entschlüsseln* "to decode", *keyphrase, passphrase* "code", Lat. *codex* "code of honour, agreement; book", *shebulet* "..?" (an ancient passphrase; *Bulle, bullla, bulletin*), *einen Code knacken* "to crack a code".

Then there's *cover*, *Hülle*, *cove, cave* and *Höhle*.

We say--though not so much in the sense of to open a book--*entdecken* "discover", which would fit as far as the front cover is a *Deckel*, but is understood as *to find*. We say figuratively *ein Buch beginnen* "to start reading or writing a book", synonym with *anfangen* and the like, which is more usually said of verbs or deverbal nouns (*ein Spiel beginnen*), and thus would usually use a verb *Ich beginne ein Buch [zu lesen]".

Comment: Vorder- und Rückseite eines Buchs werden, wie im letzten Absatz erwähnt, Deckel genannt oder insgesamt inklusive Rücken als Deckenband bezeichnet. Klappe bezieht sich wenn, dann nur auf die umgeschlagenen Laschen des Schutzumschlags, siehe Klappentext. Ein Buch auf-/zuklappen findet sich aber schon im DWB. Vielleicht [dort (u.a. Punkt 4)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GK06391#XGK06391) auch noch einmal mit den hier geäußerten Vermutungen vergleichen. Scheint mir so, wie hier beschrieben, sehr weit hergeholt zu sein.

Comment: @mtwde, ja tatsächlich sehr weit hergeholt, zumal meine Überlegung mal mit *Stockbrot* und *Knüppel-Teig* anfing. Unter *Knoblauch* ließt man von *kl-* > *kn-* ("by analogy"), vgl. insoweit Ger. *knicken* "fold, bend, snap" und En. *click* "high pitched sound, made by a switch, lock, etc.", beide zufällig *immitative* onomatopoea; vgl. auch *clique*. Falls es von weit herkommt, muss es halt von weit her geholt werden, und wenn auf dem Weg etwas verloren geht, kann es hoffentlich nachgeholt werden.